# Unable to trigger the SSIS packages from MSDB in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2016, ssis-2012, ssis-2016

Currently, the SSIS 2012 package is deployed in MSDB on SQL Server 2012, and it's working fine.

We have migrated the same packages in MSDB to SQL Server 2016 through batch utility, after created the SQL Server job  & mapping the "Master" package from MSDB (SQL Server 2016) and executing the same job, it executes successfully within 2 minutes, but package is not triggered.

Please help me resolve this issue.

Comment: Out of interest, why not switch to SSISDB? As for why, we'll need more information, such as the errors that occurred.

Comment: How to deploy the Package mode into SSIS catalog

Comment: That feature was added in 2016, @YouthIcon. From 2016 onwards, SSISDB supports both package and project deployment. As seen in [What's new in SQL Server 2016 - SQL Server 2016 Integration Services (SSIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/what-s-new-in-sql-server-2016?view=sql-server-ver15#sql-server-2016-integration-services-ssis) note that *"Incremental package deployment"* was added.

Comment: The big advantage of sql-server-2016 is the SSIS catalog/SSISDB, I'd migrate from package mode to SSIS catalog 

Check microsoft documentatino for how to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/catalog/ssis-catalog?view=sql-server-ver15)

As described my best guess would be that the user running the packages has insufficient rights to launch packages but more information is required

Comment: Tbh, even in SQL Server 2012, I'm surprised you hadn't migrated to SSISDB; it's just better™.